# For every $\epsilon\gt 0$, $|a-b|<\epsilon $ ,then b=a .

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory, proof-writing

I have done a proof by myself but not sure about it

proof: $|b-a|<\epsilon $
=$a-\epsilon $

Comment: Try `\epsilon` or `\varepsilon` to get $\epsilon$ or $\varepsilon$ respectively.

Comment: Use dollar signs to wrap up math, like `$\epsilon\gt 0$` for $\epsilon\gt 0$. Read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for an introduction on how to format your content properly on this website. You can also view how others type math on this site by right clicking on the math -> show math as -> TeX commands.

Comment: Here's a hint to get you started: suppose $|a-b|=k\gt 0$, derive a contradiction by choosing suitable $\epsilon$; hence conclude that $|a-b|=0\iff a-b=0\iff a=b$

Comment: Thanks  for  telling how to write epsilon .it worked

Comment: learner    will you please  elaborate it more that how to choose  suitable $ \epsilon $

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition about : $a = b \iff | a − b| &lt; \epsilon$, for every $\epsilon &gt; 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436553/intuition-about-a-b-iff-a-%e2%88%92-b-epsilon-for-every-epsilon-0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $\forall \epsilon > 0,\quad |a-b| < \epsilon$

If we suppose that $a \neq b$ then $|a-b| \neq 0$, we choose $\epsilon = \dfrac{|a-b|}{2} > 0$

Then $|a-b| < \dfrac{|a-b|}{2} \implies 1 < \dfrac{1}{2}$, **contradiction!**

Conclusion : $\forall \epsilon > 0,\quad |a-b| < \epsilon \implies a =b$

Comment: Thanku for such quick answer @LAGRIDA